# SQL Server: how to form a crosstab

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, crosstab

I am using SQL Server 2014.

> **How can I create a cross-table out of the straight table like the below?**

Code [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/657688/create-table-yt-store-int-week-int-xcount-int-with-two-colkey) where I try to do the multiple-pivoting.

**Sample input**

> [image]
>
> Code [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/657748/create-table-yt-store-int-week-int-xcount-int-with-two-colkey-orig) only about the sample data.

**GOAL after pivoting and reformatting of the columns by other columns**

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We repeat the case such that

```
CASE WHEN
    [City]='C1' AND [Store]='L'
THEN
    [xCount] 
END
AS 'LC1_xCount',
```

I changed the valuations a little bit to get more combinations, code [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/657688/sql-ms-crosstable-with-two-colkey).

[image]

or code here:

```
CREATE TABLE #yt
([MyID] int, [Store] nvarchar(300), [City] nvarchar(300), [Week] int, [xCount] int, [yCount] int)
;

INSERT INTO #yt
    ([MyID], [Store], [City], [Week], [xCount], [yCount])
VALUES
    (1, 'L', 'C1', 1, 96, 7),
    (2, 'L', 'C1', 1, 138, 77),
    (3, 'L2', 'C1', 1, 37, 744),
    (4, 'L', 'C1', 1, 59, 74),
    (5, 'L', 'C1', 2, 282,73333),
    (6, 'L2', 'C2', 2, 212,7333),
    (7, 'L2', 'C2', 2, 78,733),
    (8, 'L', 'C2', 2, 97,73),
    (9, 'L', 'C2', 3, 60,72222),
    (10, 'L2', 'C2', 3, 123,7222),
    (11, 'L2', 'C1', 3, 220,722),
    (12, 'L2', 'C1', 3, 87,72)
;


select [MyId], [Week], [LC1_xCount], [LC2_xCount], [L2C1_xCount], [L2C2_xCount]
    , [LC1_yCount], [LC2_yCount], [L2C1_yCount], [L2C2_yCount]
from 
(
select myid, week, store, city, xcount, ycount,
    
    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C1' AND [Store]='L'
    THEN
        [xCount] 
    END
    AS 'LC1_xCount',

    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C2' AND [Store]='L'
    THEN
        [xCount] 
    END
    AS 'LC2_xCount',

    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C1' AND [Store]='L2'
    THEN
        [xCount] 
    END
    AS 'L2C1_xCount',

    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C2' AND [Store]='L2'
    THEN
        [xCount] 
    END
    AS 'L2C2_xCount',


    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C1' AND [Store]='L'
    THEN
        [yCount] 
    END
    AS 'LC1_yCount',

    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C2' AND [Store]='L'
    THEN
        [yCount] 
    END
    AS 'LC2_yCount',

    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C1' AND [Store]='L2'
    THEN
        [yCount] 
    END
    AS 'L2C1_yCount',

    CASE WHEN
        [City]='C2' AND [Store]='L2'
    THEN
        [yCount] 
    END
    AS 'L2C2_yCount'

  from #yt
  GROUP BY myid, week, store,city, xcount, ycount
) src;
```

Answer (score 2):

This logic would work for you: 
Create an additional temp table where you store all the possible combinations of `Store` and `City`, then left join with your existing table. 
From this left join you get the "calculated" string that you will use as a column name (`C1_L_xCount`, `C1_L2_xCount`, etc).

Then apply a pivot as below:

```
select ylabel.colx, ylabel.coly, y.myid, y.week, isnull(y.xCount, 0) xCount, isnull(y.yCount, 0) yCount
into #table
from    ( 
           select distinct y3.week, y1.city, y2.store, y1.city + '_' +  y2.store + '_xCount' as colx,  y1.city + '_' + y2.store + '_yCount' as coly
           from #yt y1 cross join #yt y2 cross join #yt y3

         ) ylabel left join #yt y on y.week = ylabel.week and y.store = ylabel.store and y.city = ylabel.city


select * from #table --this is the additional table, the one used for pivoting

--this is your solution:
select myid
     , week
     , isnull(C1_L_xCount, 9) C1_L_xCount
     , isnull(C1_L2_xCount, 9 ) C1_L2_xCount
     , isnull(C2_L_xCount, 0) C2_L_xCount
     , isnull(C2_L2_xCount, 0) C2_L2_xCount
     , isnull(C1_L_yCount, 0) C1_L_yCount
     , isnull(C1_L2_yCount, 0) C1_L2_yCount
     , isnull(C2_L_yCount, 0) C2_L_yCount
     , isnull(C2_L2_yCount, 0) C2_L2_yCount
from
 (
   select *
   from #table
    pivot ( max(xCount) for colx in ( [C1_L_xCount], [C1_L2_xCount],[C2_L_xCount], [C2_L2_xCount])) p 
    pivot ( max(yCount) for coly in ( [C1_L_yCount], [C1_L2_yCount],[C2_L_yCount], [C2_L2_yCount])) q 
   where myid is not null
) t
```

Please check a working demo [here](http://rextester.com/KWVA7962).

But, if you need to dynamically add Stores and Cities, you will need to convert this into a [dynamic pivot](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Can you explain why you take cross join 2 times in the first part?

Comment: My idea was to get a combination of distinct values per week, store and city.